# Postgresql vs Python Recurring Events Speed

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

I'm building a simple calendar application with recurring events. I imagine creating two tables, one for all the events and one for the recurrences. If I make an individual event, I'll add it to the events table. If I make a recurring event, I'll add the meta-information to the recurrences table and then *all* the events in the event table (a monthly recurrence would add 12 events to the events table).

Should I implement the logic about calculating the dates of all the recurring events in Postgresql (https://justatheory.com/2008/01/postgres-recurring-events/) or with Python (our backend API)? Are there performances differences?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, in Postgres you only calculate recurrences once (on create/update), but in Python you would recaclucate them on every fetch, so Postgres should waste less cycles. However, I doubt that it's a lot of calculations. It shouldn't make a big difference for performance if it's not some sort of high-load project. I would judge it from a design perspective.

If you pre-calculate and save recurrences in Postgres, you need to make sure that:

- They are automatically deleted when the corresponding meta-record is deleted. This is easy, store a foreign key and cascade.
- They are automatically updated as time passes (in your example, you need to generate more recurrences after a year passes). This one is more tricky, I'm not sure what is the "correct" way to do scheduled updates in Postgres.

If you calculate in Python, you get rid of this problem with scheduled updates, you just create recurrences on every fetch. But you lose the beautiful ability to just fetch the data as is, from *the single source of truth*, and just present it to the user. The logic layer becomes more thick.

Overall, the Postgres solution seems nicer to me. I haven't looked much into the article you've linked, but it mentiones views. This probably means that you also have an option to calculate recurrences on each select, but in Postgres instead of Python. I'd just pick whatever is easier to implement and maintain.

If you're really only concerned about performance, I'm sorry, I'm not competent enough to analyze it.

Comment: Another way to write the Python code is that every time a new recurrence is added, we add a row to the recurrence table and also all the events in the recurrence to the events table.